# Django MPTT ordering

Tags: python, django, recursion, tree, mptt

I'm using MPTT tree structure in my Django project to organise comments. I have only 2 level : comment and comment of comment
Everything works perfectly except the ordering.

I would like to sort all Comment that don't have parents by creation date ascendent ("-creation_date") and all comment that has a parent by creation date descendant ("creation_date"). 
Basically it's like the comments are working on the Facebook wall. (you alway see the latest comment on top but the comments within a comment are in a reverse order)

In my class Comment I have the following MPTTMeta : order_insertion_by=['creation_date']

I hope I'll get some help.

Thank you

Comment: Do you've coded your own tree? i.e. do you've created your tree over your own models? if so, please add your models.py or at least the related part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been sitting here for five minutes and I can't think of a way to do this in SQL given the data structure you are describing.  To begin with, I would suggest that you separate your data into Posts and Comments, rather than just having one sort of data object.  Then you can do a join to gather the comments together with your posts and give different ordering to each.

Also, an MPTT seems like overkill for a two layer tree.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution so I forgot to check back.
I played around with the mptt structure and django functions ...
Thanks